# Why is the Autodesk Forge Viewer DiffTool not rendering the left side model in side-by-side view?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Autodesk Forge Viewer extension DiffTool in side-by-side mode does not render diff model (the left side model) and the left part is empty. The both models are loaded and everything works in overlay mode. Even click and select events works on left side. Nothing is hide or isolated, but nothing can be seen.
[Viewer DiffTool side-by-side view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjaT.png)

I expect to see a rendered 3D model on the left

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that there's a regression in the `sidebyside` mode of the `Autodesk.DiffTool` extension that's been reported today (May 23rd). The engineering team is looking into the issue.

In the meantime, please consider adding `useSplitScreenExtension: true` to the extension options which solves the issue.